# Is the Haskell classy-prelude different from the GHC 7.10 prelude

Tags: haskell

In the github readme for [classy-prelude](https://github.com/snoyberg/classy-prelude) it says:

> It is worth noting that classy-prelude largely front-ran changes that the community made to the base Prelude in GHC 7.10.

Does this mean that, as a user of GHC 7.10, I shouldn't consider classy-prelude. In other words, is classy meant to address deficiencies in pre-7.10 preludes which are no longer present in 7.10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This only refers to the Foldable/Traversable instances being added to `Prelude`. There are many other features in `classy-prelude` that are not offered in `Prelude`.